# Localhost: Why does {{ asset.url }} return {{siteUrl}}/path in the browser?

Tags: assets, siteurl

I'm very new at Craft templating, and I can't seem to get an asset to link correctly in the browser.

```
{% block content %}
    <article>
        <h1>{{ entry.title }}</h1>
        {{ siteUrl }}
        <p>Posted on {{ entry.postDate.format('F d, Y') }}</p>
        {{ entry.blog_body }}
        {% for asset in entry.blog_featured_image %}
            <img src="{{asset.url}}" alt="{{asset.title}}" />
        {% endfor %}
    </article>
{% endblock %}
```

Becomes this:

```
<article>
  <h1>New Blog 1</h1>
  http://localhost/craftcms/public/
  <p>Posted on January 15, 2017</p>
  <p>"Body Text"</p>
  <img src="{{ siteUrl }}assets/images/image.png" alt="title">
</article>
```

when output to a browser.

{{ siteUrl }} will display the path just fine, but when I'm using {{asset.url}} and it gets changed to {{siteUrl}} it doesn't create the path, it just stays at siteUrl. This is really confusing me.

Why doesn't {{ siteUrl }} return the base path when it's used in the asset.url?

Comment: In your asset settings for that source do you have something like `{{ siteUrl }}/images` in the input field? If so, try changing it to `{siteUrl}` and see if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What field type is blog_featured_image? Just an image asset?
Does it work with

`<img src="{{ asset.getUrl() }}" alt="{{asset.title}}" />` ?

Comment: The blog_featured_image is just an image asset.

Comment: I attempted to use it within the ElementCriteriaModel doc (https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/craft.assets) but I couldn't get it to work.

The base path and base url in the Settings > Assets are produced exactly (if I use {siteUrl} it outputs {siteUrl}assets/images rather than "http://example.com/assets/images"

Unfortunately, using the same code you suggested didn't do it either. I'm missing something obvious, I'm sure, but I can't find it.

Comment: How does your general.php look like? Maybe a typo there?

Comment: There are no additional settings in general.php yet, I tried adding some siteUrl updates and have since removed them, so now it's empty. I realize now that it's the siteUrl that I added into the asset settings that's being passed through, so I think my question is answered and I need to research dynamic asset settings paths. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need the `.getUrl();` I also suggest that you have a look at the [Imager plugin](https://github.com/aelvan/Imager-Craft) for a more flexible use of images in your site.

Comment: asset.getUrl() DOES get the url, but it omits the main base url (in this instance "localhost/public/" and leaves in {siteUrl} in the finished code: ( I.E. {{asset.getUrl()}} == "{siteUrl}assets/filename.jpg" )